# UV unwraping problem

Tags: mesh, texturing, materials, uv

Why is this happening?And how could I solve it?
 [image: enter code here]

Comment: Have you tried plugging a Texture Coordinate node into your images, choosing UV as the input? That is all I can see from the screen grab.

Comment: Please be descriptive in what is wrong with the image you are showing and what you expecting/want.

Comment: @RayMairlot I don't know how to explain it's but the whiteish part of the boat...I don't want that

Comment: Looks rather like the lighter faces are facing the wrong way.  Go into edit mode-->Faces, select the light coloured faces  and try flipping them from the toolbox at left if you haven't done so already.  (T for toolbox, CTL-Z to undo)